# How to load JSP page on next/prev click of Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

Earlier I had scrollbar, where different icons were displayed. on click of particular icon, jsp page was displayed. but i need to replaced it with carousel.

on next/prev click following function should be called:

```
 function testing(index) {
        var tableLength = tableAddArray.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < tableLength; i++) {  
            if (i == index) {
                selectedElement= tableAddArray[i].id;
            }
            console.log("selectedElement:: "+selectedElement);
        }
        createElement();
    }


function createElement() {
    var request ="/xyzz/abcdd?objectName="; 
    var attributesToSend = "&action=add" ; 
    attributesToSend += "&ref="+document.getElementsByName("ref")[0].value ; 
    document.getElementsByName("action")[0].value = "add"; 
    if (selectedElement != null) { request += selectedElement; 
    if (selectedElement == "1") {equest += "&condOp=5"; } 
    else if (selectedElement == "2") {request += "&dest=2";} 
    request += attributesToSend; location.href=request; 
    //from here other processing is done to get corresponding data from DB 
    } 
}
```

then in carousel,:

```
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false"> 
    <div class="carousel-inner"> 
    <div class="carousel-item"> 
    <c:choose> 
    <c:when test="${requestScope.objectName == '2'}"> 
    <jsp:include page="2nd_Slide.jsp"></jsp:include> </c:when>
     <c:when test="${requestScope.objectName == '3'}"> 
    <jsp:include page="3rd_slide.jsp"></jsp:include> </c:when> 
    </c:choose>
     </div> 
     <a class="carousel-control-prev" ..> 
    <a class="carousel-control-next" ..> 
    </div>
```

Hence i need to set objectname at 0th index as well. I dont know how to call js before 0th slide of carousel is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanna register an event handler on slide action of the carousel. Something like this

```
$('#carousel_id').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () 
  //load jsp like before with click on icons
)
```

Set some id on the element that needs to trigger jsp load

**NOTE:** check out *slid.bs.carousel* for post slide event handling

**EDIT:**

Try:

```
  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-   ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
        <p class="d-block w-100"> 
        Slide 1
        <div id="jspdiv1"></div>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <p class="d-block w-100">
        Slide 2
        <div id="jspdiv2"></div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

  <script>
  var ind = 0;
  $('#carouselExampleControls').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if(e.direction =='right'){
     ind++;
     console.log("right "+ind);
     $("#jspdiv1").text("Slided right "+ind);
    }
    else if(e.direction == 'left'){
         ind--;
     console.log("left "+ind);
     $("#jspdiv2").text("Slided left "+ind);
    }
    console.log(e);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi thankyou so much,
But Actually, I have an array of objectName.
by default a[0] value of object name will be set in request parameter.
And that will trigger jsp page.
then on click of carousel previous or next, either a[i+1] or a[i-1] value of objectName will be set in request parameter.

Even with your suggestion, I am not able to do so.

I am totally new to js and jsp.
Could you please provide sample code.

Comment: @Gun added some code, it does not load the required script , just uses an incremental value and substitutes it in place of a div element (which can be placed anywhere across the page). You can use this incremental value to be passed on to the jsp as per your need. hope it helps

Comment: Hi, If possible could u plz help me further,

I have called a method testing(index) in your given code: 
<code>
function testing(index) {
 var tableLength = tableAddArray.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < tableLength; i++) {  
      if (i == index) {
       selectedElement= tableAddArray[i].id;
      }
     }
     createElement();
}
</code>

But I also need to call this testing() method for zeroth index. I mean when first slide of carousel is displayed.

Comment: @Gun , statically put it inside the div of first slide. Later on, override it with new one. Can't help you more without some code on  how you are loading the jsp

Comment: Just a suggestion, better update your question with these details

Comment: Hi, have considered your suggestion. updated the question.